# Replace one fields value with another fields value for every row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to take the value of one field in a database table and replace it with the value of another concatenating it with an arbitrary string in the process. Here's what I've tried:

```
UPDATE table SET FieldA = CONCAT(FieldB, ' - arbitrary string')
```

The outcome of the above was "0 rows affected".

My table currently has 60 rows, FieldB contains some basic text relevant to each row, FieldA is currently empty for every row. I would like FieldA to contain that row's FieldB text, plus a little extra but the extra will be the same for every row.

Comment: Since you're not applying any `WHERE` condition - this may be if your table is empty. Is it empty?

Comment: Your statement [looks good](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). Maybe you left something important out for this question?

Comment: Table is not empty. I'll edit my question and elaborate a bit more.

Comment: [Works fine](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a6ec/1)

Comment: Is FieldA or FieldB an Integer?

Comment: both are varchar(255)

Comment: Based on what you addedd...UPDATE table SET FieldB = CONCAT(FieldA, ' - arbitrary string')

Comment: Please provide a fully functional [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) which shows example data, your update statement and the wrong result.

Comment: Sorry SQLDBA got A and B the wrong way around in my edit. I've corrected it.

Comment: Please post sqlfiddle as its very easy for us to guide you

Comment: OK I'll do that ASAP. Wasnt aware of sqlfiddle, so I'll have to figure it out first :)

Comment: Pay attention to NULL values. Maybe your destination column FieldB has been defined as NOT NULL while you have NULLS in FieldA.

Comment: Should the question say "FieldA is currently empty for every row."? At the moment B has some text, A is empty; A needs to be B+' - arbitrary string'?

Comment: Yes AjV, you're right. Sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
UPDATE table SET FieldA = CONCAT(IFNULL(FieldB,'No Value'), ' - arbitrary string')
```

Comment: FieldB (the one I want to copy to the other) has data for every row. FieldA, where the data should be copied to is empty for every row.

Comment: I tried it anyway, and this is working for me. Thanks, I'll accept your answer.